# Adding U.FL connector to XBee

Tags: antenna, xbee, pcb-antenna

I recently bought two XBee Series 2 Pros, and I want to increase the range on them. I found an appropriate 2.4GHz antenna with a U.FL connector. I already have one XBee with a U.FL connector and from what I can tell the PCB layout is exactly the same except for the absence of the connector. Would I be able to remove the two wire antennae and solder U.FL connectors on and use them instead?

Comment: I would imagine that if you remove the wire antennas first then that should be possible. However, I am not sure. I also have a couple of XBee Pro S2B modules, but with PCB antennas. I was wondering the same thing, could I add an additional U.FL connector, or would the existing PCB antenna mess up the signal? If I cut the PCD trace close to the output, then that should be OK, or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wire antenna is removed, then a soldered uFL connector will allow a functional antenna to be attached.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if you remove the wire antennas first then that should be possible. The answers to these two questions seem to imply that it is possible:

- [Solder wire antenna on XBee Pro u.fl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174828/solder-wire-antenna-on-xbee-pro-u-fl?lq=1)
- [XBee short wire antenna replacement to longer wire?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/xbee-short-wire-antenna-replacement-to-longer-wire)