# Solder wire antenna on XBee Pro u.fl

Tags: antenna, xbee

I'd like to buy one XBee Pro with Wire Antenna, and another with an u.fl connector. The problem is that, on the only website I can buy them, the U.Fl one costs 20 € less than the one with a Wire Antenna: I wish I could keep these 20 bucks.

On the other hand, I've already got two unused XBee with Wire Antenna: I wonder whether I could unsolder the U.Fl connector of one XBee Pro, and instead solder the wire antenna of one unused XBee.

So, Could I just replace an U.Fl connector with a Wire Antenna ? Won't this lower the range ? Are the XBee w/ ufl connector different from XBee w/ wire antenna, except for the antenna/connector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main consideration here is the frequency of operation - if the unused XBee and the one with the U.FL connection operate at the same frequency, you'll be fine.  It won't make an appreciable difference whether you attach a U.FL antenna or if you solder the other wire antenna on.

See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/xbee-short-wire-antenna-replacement-to-longer-wire?rq=1) for a similar answer.

Comment: And should I unsolder the U.FL connector after soldering the new wire antenna ?

Comment: It might be easier to unsolder the connector first, then solder the wire antenna to where the connector used to be